# Effectively convert little endian byte slice to int32

Tags: go, integer, serialization

I have a data stream of bytes and I'd like to get a little endian encoded int32 from four bytes. Is there a better way than to do this like the following code?

```
package main

func read_int32(data []byte) int32 {
    return int32(uint32(data[0]) + uint32(data[1])<<8 + uint32(data[2])<<16 + uint32(data[3])<<24)
}

func main() {
    println(read_int32([]byte{0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF})) // -2
    println(read_int32([]byte{0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00})) // 255
}
```

The code above seems to work fine, but perhaps there is a built-in function in Go that I've missed or there is a super cool hack that does that in one instruction?

Comment: This page should help. http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ReadVarint

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`encoding/binary` package may have what you need. Check this: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#example_Read

Your code with modified `read_int32` function could be:

```
package main
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func read_int32(data []byte) (ret int32) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &ret)
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(read_int32([]byte{0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF})) // -2
    fmt.Println(read_int32([]byte{0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00})) // 255
}
```

Also you can interpret big endian by replacing `binary.LittleEndian` with `binary.BigEndian`

Comment: That looks fine, I'll try it out and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a really late answer, however there are 2 different ways to do it.

```
func readInt32(b []byte) int32 {
    // equivalnt of return int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(b))
    return int32(uint32(b[0]) | uint32(b[1])<<8 | uint32(b[2])<<16 | uint32(b[3])<<24)
}

// this is much faster and more efficient, however it won't work on appengine 
// since it doesn't have the unsafe package.
// Also this would blow up silently if len(b) < 4.
func ReadInt32Unsafe(b []byte) int32 {
    return *(*int32)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))
}
```

Comment: How to modify func readInt32 to return float32 value?
I'd tried to just change `return int32(...)` to `retrun float32(...)` and get wrong data.

Comment: @Борис, replace `int32` with `math.Float32frombits`.  See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/aG8GRNPRh3). Internally, it uses the `unsafe` cast, but is safe because it operates on a `uint32` instead of a slice.

Comment: how do you convert an `int` into `[]byte` ?

Comment: The `ReadInt32Unsafe` approach is neither faster nor correct.  It breaks on big endian platforms and on little endian platforms, a smart compiler will generate essentially the same code for both.